Python, использования ярлыка для передачи в него пути
Я хочу использовать ярлык на рабочем столе (по типу корзины), который будет перемещать файлы в указанную папку при перетаскивании их на этот ярлык.
Как можно реализовать такую функциональность с помощью Python?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные способы и примеры кода.

Можно добиться желаемого результата через аргументы командной строки:
1)
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    file_name = file_path.split("\\")[-1]  # Получаем имя файла из пути
    print("Путь к файлу:", file_path)
    print("Имя файла:", file_name)
else:
    print("Файл не был передан в аргументах командной строки.")

input() # Для теста, что бы консоль сразу не закрывалась





Устанавливаем Pyinstaller: Win+R -> cmd -> Enter -> pip install pyinstaller -> pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/133.py"

Получаем .exe файл -> делаем на него ярлык -> перетаскиваем на ярлык файл.

3)
Теперь, когда у нас есть путь к файлу, мы можем его открывать, удалять, перемещать и выполнять другие операции.
